pyodbc DB2 global variable not found for stored procedure
We have to call a stored procedure on a DB2 database. Following the instructions from this ticket pyodbc python linux iSeriesAccess driver - stored procedure - capture output parameters? we have the following python code.
import json
import traceback
import pyodbc
from modules.utils import print_message
from modules import secrets_manager
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(f"EVENT {event}")
    error_str = ''
    tenant = context.invoked_function_arn.split(":")[-1]
    aws_account_id = context.invoked_function_arn.split(':')[-4]
    aws_region = context.invoked_function_arn.split(':')[3]
    function_name = context.invoked_function_arn.split(":")[-2]
    result = 0.0
    try:
        secret = json.loads(secrets_manager.get_secret(tenant,aws_region))
        conn = pyodbc.connect(f"DSN=IBM i Access;SYSTEM={secret['ip']};PORT={secret['port']};DATABASE={secret['database']};UID={secret['username']};PWD={secret['password']};naming=1;dbq=,MAX550?????")
        crsr = conn.cursor()
        crsr.execute("CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE AOMO DECIMAL DEFAULT 0.0")
        crsr.execute("CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE LSEQ DECIMAL DEFAULT 0.0")
        crsr.execute("CREATE OR REPLACE VARIABLE RETC CHAR")

        params = ('PB', event['orderNo'], '', '', '', '', 0,)
        print(params)
        crsr.execute("call MIE550EC.Z1NS910B(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,AOMO,LSEQ,RETC)", params)
        rows = crsr.fetchall()
        while rows:
            print(rows)
            if crsr.nextset():
                rows = crsr.fetchall()
            else:
                rows = None
        crsr.execute("values(AOMO)")
        print(crsr.fetchall())
    except Exception as e:
        error_str = f"{str(e)}\n{traceback.format_exc()}"
    finally:
        if tenant == "prd" and error_str != "":
            print_message(tenant, event, error_str,function_name)
        elif tenant != "prd":
            print_message(tenant, event, error_str,function_name)
        error_str = ""
        return result

When the code is run the following error is returned stating that it cannot find the RETC global variable I created.
"('42S22', '[42S22] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0206 - Column or global variable RETC not found. (-206) (SQLPrepare)')\nTraceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 27, in lambda_handler\n    crsr.execute(\"call MIE550EC.Z1NS910B(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,AOMO,LSEQ,RETC)\", params)\npyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S22', '[42S22] [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0206 - Column or global variable RETC not found. (-206) (SQLPrepare)')\n"

I am at a loss as to how to resolve the issue.

What is your exact version of Db2-for-i ?   Are you able to create a variable , set it to a some value, and retrieve that value via the crsr.execute(...) i.e independently of stored procedures?  What is the programming-language of your stored-procedure implementation?

From the error [DB2 for i5/OS]. I am trying to return the value via crsr.execute("values(AOMO)") as per the above. My question is why it is not finding the global variable I have created

i5 is not "exact version" , I mean that your question should detail the cumulative PTF level , ask your admin for the plain text output of "Display PTF Status (DSPPTF)"   Your symptom might be caused by antique versions.
